# "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" statement does not work in qt sqlite

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt-creator

I am using sqlite with qt creator. I have a class that manages sqlite database connectivity and other operations. This is the constructor code:

```
dbconnector::dbconnector()
{
    digi_db = openDb("QSQLITE","digibill.db");
    QSqlQuery qry;


            // Creating table owner
            qry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS owner (owner_id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, company_name VARCHAR(30), country VARCHAR(30), address VARCHAR(100), city VARCHAR(30), state VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(30), phone VARCHAR(30), website VARCHAR(30),  tin VARCHAR(30), currency VARCHAR(30), additional_info VARCHAR(30), logo BLOB)" );
            if( !qry.exec() )
                qDebug() << qry.lastError();
            else
                qDebug() << "Table1 created!";

            // Creating table company_details
            qry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS company_details (company_id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, company_name VARCHAR(30), contact VARCHAR(15) )" );
            if( !qry.exec() )
                qDebug() << qry.lastError();
            else
                qDebug() << "Table2 created!";

            // Creating table product_details
            qry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_details (product_id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, product_name VARCHAR(30), price FLOAT, company_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES company_details(company_id)  )" );
            if( !qry.exec() )
                qDebug() << qry.lastError();
            else
                qDebug() << "Table3 created!";


            // Creating table client_details
            qry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client_details (client_id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, company_name VARCHAR(30),contact_name VARCHAR(40), country VARCHAR(30), address VARCHAR(50),city VARCHAR(30), state VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(80), phone VARCHAR(15), website VARCHAR(80), tin VARCHAR(30)  )" );
            if( !qry.exec() )
                qDebug() << qry.lastError();
            else
                qDebug() << "Table4 created!";

            // Creating table invoice_details
            qry.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoice_details (invoice_id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date_of_invoice TEXT, client_id INTEGER, product_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client_details(client_id), FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES product_details(product_id)  )" );
            if( !qry.exec() )
                qDebug() << qry.lastError();
            else
                qDebug() << "Table5 created!";

}
```

The function opendb creates the database and the code is given below:

```
QSqlDatabase dbconnector::openDb(const QString &driver, const QString &name) const
{
    QSqlDatabase db;

    // contains() default argument is initialized to default connection
    if (QSqlDatabase::contains())
    {
        db = QSqlDatabase::database(QLatin1String(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection), false);
    }
    else
    {
        db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(driver.toUpper());
    }

    db.setDatabaseName(name);

    if (!db.isValid())
    {
        // Log error (last error: db.lastError().text()) and throw exception
    }

    if (!db.open())
    {
        // Log error (last error: db.lastError().text()) and throw exception
    }
     qDebug() <<"Database main open";
    return db;
}
```

The problem is that every time i create an object of the class, the query gets executed and i get the output as:

```
Database main open
Table1 created!
Table2 created!
Table3 created!
Table4 created!
Table5 created!
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you think that anything is wrong?

Comment: The execution of the query will not fail if the table exists so you should see your "Table1 created!" message even if the table existed before the call.

Comment: oh...k..i got it now...thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There is actually nothing wrong with your code, but you should notice that the return value of `QSqlQuery.exec()` just means the execution of your query is successful, it doesn't means you created a new table.

If you really want to check the table is exist or not, you can use

`SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='tablename';`

(replace `tablename` as the name you want to check) and check the query result. but at most of the time you can just use `IF NOT EXISTS` without any worry, in your case, only use `if (!qry.exec()) {}` to handle error is okay.